# php mysqli_connect Connection Error (0 trying to connect to localhost database using MAMP

Tags: php, mamp

Here is my code, and below the message I received.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'root');
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    die('Connect Error ('.mysqli_connect_errno().') '.mysqli_connect_error());
  }
 echo 'Connected successfully.';
 if(!$con) {
    echo "not connected to server";
}
if(!mysqli_select_db('$con', 'tutorial')) {
    echo('Connection Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
        . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$Name = $_POST['username'];
$Email = $_POST['email'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO person (Name, Email) VALUES ('', $Name', '$Email')";
if(!mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
    echo "not inserted"  . mysqli_error();
}
else {
    echo "inserted";

}?>
```

AND THIS IS THE MESSAGE I RECEIVED

Connected successfully.Connection Error (0) not inserted

Comment: You are missing a single quote at
 $sql = "INSERT INTO person (Name, Email) VALUES ('', $Name', '$Email')";

Comment: Remove the quotes surrounding `$con` in your select_db, and die after the connection error or else it's going to continue on. As single quotes, it's just passing in the string `$con`, and not the actual connection object.

Comment: You are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). **This will take care of any pesky quoting issues that may occur.**

Comment: why unnecessary empty string ? as we can see you're trying to insert only 2 column values. Also missing a single quotes before `$Name`

Comment: Insert values should start with `('$Name'` or you should define the column you want the empty value in.

Comment: @aynber I think you nailed it, post it as an answer so we can vote for it

Comment: @Corin I try not to answer questions where I voted to close as a typo.. :-)